# android - required layout_attribute is missing

Tags: android

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <gradient
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#4ccbff"
        android:endColor="#24b2eb"
        android:startColor="#24b2eb" />
 <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

The above code shows " required `layout_height` attribute is missing" on the line no **4**

&

"required `layout_height` and `layout_width` attribute is missing" on the line no **11**.

Comment: It should tell you which attribute is missing as well. Seems to be layout_height in the first case and both layout_height and layout_width in the second case

Comment: Yes, in the second case it shows error on both layout.
I've included android:layout_height="wrap_content" in the code, but it shows same error.

Comment: Its layout_height, not height.

Comment: it should me "android:layout_height" instead of "android:height"

Comment: I have tried too by adding android:layout_height, but still it shows same error :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is to remove any layout information from shape, gradient and corners.
Your file should look like the following.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#4ccbff"
        android:endColor="#24b2eb"
        android:startColor="#24b2eb" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Yes, shapes are no layouts.